# How to extract one topic for one document using LDA

Tags: nlp, lda, topic-modeling

We are aware of that LDA is designed to work with a number of documents and extract k topics from them. However our goal is to extract one single topic for one single document using LDA. Our first approach is:

1. Clean data (lowercase, lemmatize, remove stopwords, punctuations, number, etc).
2. Vectorize using Countvectorize.
3. LDA (1 topic)

One interesting observation is that the top 10 keywords of the output of LDA are exactly those 10 words that are most frequently appeared in the document(totally count based). We would like to ask two questions:

1. Does this observation make any sense?
2. Any other ways to achieve our goal?

Comment: Using LDA with just one topic will, indeed, simply give you a slightly fuzzy version of word frequencies. It really makes no sense to use just one topic. Can you describe your problem a bit more? What is the context? What do you need to know the "topic" for? Is there a set of possible topics you want to choose from? (this could even be something like wikipedia pages, but without some reference context, your task makes no sense)

Comment: Sure! The big picture is that I am given a keyword and a text string. I would like to extract the topic from the text and calculate a relevance score(using Spacy word similarity) between the topic and the keyword.

Comment: I want to make this an API that can work on any given pair of keyword and text string. I am aware of how LDA works but I do not want to do topic modeling on a corpus(a number of text strings). You are right that it will give a slightly fuzzy version of word frequencies. It is similar to my observation is that the top 10 keywords of the output of LDA are exactly those 10 words that are most frequently appeared in the document(totally count based). Does this make sense? What other method would you recommend?

Comment: Could you update the question with the detail of the task you want to perform please? I don't think topic modelling makes sense in your use case. Does the keyword come from some predefined knowledge base or something like that? Is there an obvious way to represent it as a topic? (generally single words are rather ambiguous in this way).  A simple approach would be average word embeddings dot prodcuted with that of the topic query word. If you've enough examples to train a model, try BERT or googles universal sentence encoder + an embedding of the query topic word as the basis of a classifier.

Comment: Have you found an answer yet? or how did you handle it